# Phonegap: in app purchase auto-renewing subscription?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, command-line-interface

I'm experimenting with phonegap and in app purchase. I'm all new to in app purchase.

I'm using this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase

**Basically what I need to do is to create a simple app that gives a 3 days free trial and then stops working or gives an error or alert or anything (just stops working and prevents users to use the app) until they have an active auto-renewing subscription.**

Every single information and tutorials that I found so far are about Consumables and non-consumable products.

What I need to learn is the `auto-renewing subscription purchase`.

I followed this guide to create a product in itunes connect account:

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/HOWTO#create-ios-applications

I have added this code in my Phonegap projet:

```
// We must wait for the "deviceready" event to fire
// before we can use the store object.
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeStore, false);

function initializeStore() {

    // Let's set a pretty high verbosity level, so that we see a lot of stuff
    // in the console (reassuring us that something is happening).
    store.verbosity = store.INFO;

    // We register a dummy product. It's ok, it shouldn't
    // prevent the store "ready" event from firing.
    store.register({
        id:    "XXXXXXX",
        alias: "Upgrade Membership",
        type:  store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION
    });

    // When every goes as expected, it's time to celebrate!
    // The "ready" event should be welcomed with music and fireworks,
    // go ask your boss about it! (just in case)
    store.ready(function() {
        console.log("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");

        alert('\\o/ STORE READY \\o/');
    });

    // After we've done our setup, we tell the store to do
    // it's first refresh. Nothing will happen if we do not call store.refresh()
    store.refresh();
}
```

Now, the questions that I have are:

1. is there anything specific that i need to do to check to see if
   the users have active subscription? Or apple would do that
   automatically for me?
2. what other things I need to know about in app auto-renewing
       purchase feature?
3. is `type:  store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION` for auto renew subscription?
4. is `id:    "XXXXXXX",`  my app bundle ID or its the Product ID
       which is shown in the itunes connect?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) is there anything specific that I need to do to check to see if the users have an active subscription? Or apple would do that automatically for me?

--Make a request as store.get(productId) and check status of product to see if the user is already subscribed.

3) is type:  store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION for auto renew the subscription?

--Yes that is correct

4) is id:    "XXXXXXX", my app bundle ID or its the Product ID which is shown in the iTunes connect?

-- No it's not ID, use ProductID